# SVG Rectangle inheriting width and height of parent

Tags: html, svg

In a nutshell, what I have is an SVG markup like this

```
<svg width="700" height="700">
    <g width="700" height="700">
        <g width="66" height="140" class="bar"></g>
        <g width="132" height="140" class="bar"></g>
        <g width="99" height="140" class="bar"></g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Now I want to place SVG rectangles inside every bar. These rectangles should fill their according parenting bars. I checked specification of rectangle and found that percentage units allowed when we use width as attr, but they could have two possible meanings:
1. percentage of viewport;
2. percentage of bounding box.
As far as I have width and height of bar groups set, it should work for me. But it doesn't — when I set width of rect element to 100%, it occupies whole SVG box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<g>` element does not have `width` and `height` attributes.  Groups just encapsulate elements, they don't control their position or size.  You could however use inner `<svg>` elements (see below).

Also, you have to set the position of SVG elements.  SVG does not have any sort of automatic layout as HTML does.

```
<svg width="700" height="700">
    <g>
        <svg x="0"   width="66" height="140" class="bar"></svg>
        <svg x="100" width="132" height="140" class="bar"></svg>
        <svg x="200" width="99" height="140" class="bar"></svg>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ok, got it. Regarding position control it could be done with transform attribute of group (it seems that this attribute could be inherited).

Comment: Yes, that's right.  If you set the `transform` attribute of a group, you are not actually setting the position of the group, you are setting a transform that all of the group's descendants inherit.